# Present tab bar controller based on a set of conditions

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, swift5

In, one of my multiple UIViewControllers, I have a sign in button that takes you to a tab bar scene. The viewcontrollers shown in the tab bar scene depends on the type of account selected. In another scene, there's a button which updates it's titlelabel based on type of account. Here is what I have done.

```
class SIgn_In: UIViewController {
   let tabbar = UITabBarController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}


@IBAction func didTapSignIn(_ sender: Any) {
   guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "vc") as? AccountViewController else{return}
    let firstVc = First()
    let secondVc = Second()
    let thirdVc = Third()

    if vc.text == "accountType1" {
        
        tabbar.setViewControllers([firstVc,secondVc], animated: false)

    } else if vc.text == "accounttype2" {
        tabbar.setViewControllers([thirdVc,firstVc,secondVc], animated: false)
        
    }
    
    present(tabbar,animated: true)

}
```

In the accountViewController, I have this code.

```
 class AccountViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!


public var accountType:String = ""
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    accountType = button.currentTitle!
   
  }
```

But I'm not quite getting what I expected, what am I missing? Please help

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing what you were expecting, but....  You create `vc` as a new instance of a view controller and then test whether it contains some text.  Even if it had a `text` property, the content of that property would always be the same for a new instance.

Comment: I was expecting the Tabbar to update its child viewcontrollers based on the given conditions but it's not working.

Comment: Try printing `vc.text` to see what's happening...or use the debugger to inspect it.  But the main problem is expecting that a value you get from a new instance is somehow going to be different from one time to the next.

Comment: Yes, I checked and it's true, the value does not change. What do you suggest I do to change the text property each time a different account is selected from the button click

Comment: The simplest way for a single piece of data is probably to have your `AccountViewController` save it somewhere shared such as `UserDefaults`.  Then your sign in controller could read that instead of trying to extract it from a different controller.  (If you end up having more data to share among controllers, look up how an app structure like MVC works.)